# It is possible to show notifications on the notification bar if the app is in fullscreen mode?

Tags: android, notifications, android-c2dm, statusbar

i have my app in fullscreen mode:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I want to show push notifications on my app in the status bar.

Will the status bar be shown when my app receives a push notification if my app is in full screen mode?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No..you will be able to see the notification in the Notification bar after you come to home screen from the app! (Or open the home screen, by clicking the Home button). You won't be able to see the notification if your app is in fullscreen.

Comment: and what can i do to solve this if i need to mantain the fullscreen mode?

Comment: I would recommend bringing up a Dialog in the Activity for that particular notification (if you can somehow figure out how to use this push notification) because a notification in fullscreen is out of the question.

Comment: i want to show notification as devices full screen ??
So how its possible in android ?

Comment: What a disappointment, it would have been cool to have such a capability in Android. Well, thanks anyway for saving me the trouble.